# Accessing Hidden Method Error for Android Project

Tags: android

I have been developing Android projects. I take an error for the API 28 version. it is "Dedect the problem with API compatibility".

I saw the accessing hidden method error in Logcat. Hidden Method is
"Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setTransitionVisibility(I)V (dark greylist, linking)"

How can solve this problem?